# Why was blowing up most of the bridges advantageous in Pride and Prejudice and Zombies (movie)?

Tags: movie, zombie, pride-prejudice-zombies

As I understand it, the initial setting of Pride and Prejudice and Zombies (movie) is this:

London has a giant wall around it, is safe from the zombies.  The Royal Canal is a moat at some distance from London and its giant wall.  The zombies were originally contained outside the Royal Canal, but eventually breached one of the bridges and invaded the "In-Between" (land between the giant wall around London and the Royal Canal).

After this breach, all the bridges except one were destroyed.  However, I cannot understand why this would offer an advantage against the zombies.  There were zombies on both sides of the Royal Canal by this point, and destroying the bridges or leaving them shouldn't make a difference.  What advantage did destroying any of the bridges, let alone nearly all of them, give the remaining living people once zombies were found on both sides of the Royal Canal?

**Please note** that I am *not* referring to the events at the end of the movie,

> when London falls and its populace succumbs to the zombie plague and the final bridge over the Royal Canal is destroyed.  The defensive advantage of this move is clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

The script never mentions it explicitly.
But what you see happening is that there are militia and checkpoints everywhere. You are inspected head to toe even to get into a card party.

To try and get some logical sense of it:

1. Originally the royal canal is created to protect London and the surrounding countryside.

   > To protect the living, the Grand Barrier was built.
   >   A one hundred foot wall,
   >   encircling London.
   >   Then excavation began on the royal canal.
   >   A vast mote thirty fathoms deep
   >   surrounding both the city and its walls.
2. Then the “unmentionables” breach one bridge ***from the outside*** and infest The Inbetween.

   > In the second battle of Kent. One of the bridges
   >   that cross the royal canal was breached.
   >   Ravenous zombie hordes massacred
   >   every villager of The Inbetween.
3. The bridges are destroyed to ***isolate*** The Inbetween from the rest of the countryside. So, to protect both sides from each other.

   > When the battle was finally won, he ordered
   >   the destruction of all the bridges, save one.
   >   Hingham Bridge.
4. All of the countryside now is... kinda safe. Liveable, if you take precautions. Spy-holes in all entry doors! Never stated out loud, but there should be people living and travelling both in The Inbetween and in the surrounding countryside. All country houses in the movie are outside the In Between, but several excursions are into The Inbetween, for example to St. Lazarus.

   > Many believed the enemy was finally vanquished.
   >   The gentry began to leave the safe confines
   >   of London's defences.

So the single bridge is one of the most important of many many checkpoints, and compartmentalization is the name of the game.

Reference:
http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=pride-and-prejudice-and-zombies